# cannot access ‘/sbin/udevd’: No such file or directory

Tags: 15.10

After 15.10 dist upgrade I get the following error using apt-get?

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libboost-iostreams1.55.0* libhiredis0.10* libhogweed2* libicu52* libnettle4* libregexp-common-perl*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 6 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 29.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
chmod: cannot access ‘/sbin/udevd’: No such file or directory
E: Problem executing scripts DPkg::Pre-Invoke 'chmod -x /sbin/udevd'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Comment: `/sbin/udevd` isn't longer available in Wily. But the removal scripts of the packages in your question seem to depend on it. Try the following `sudo touch /sbin/udevd ; sudo apt-get autoremove --purge; sudo rm /sbin/udevd`

Comment: If that not work, run `sudo dpkg -r --force-all libboost-iostreams1.55.0 libhiredis0.10`

Comment: I can't believe sudo touch /sbin/udevd worked lol :P please add answer so I can accept.

Comment: :) sure. Answer added :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/sbin/udevd` isn't longer available in Wily. But the removal scripts of the packages in your question seem to depend on it. Try the following

```
sudo touch /sbin/udevd; sudo apt-get autoremove --purge; sudo rm /sbin/udevd
```

If that does not work, run

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-all libboost-iostreams1.55.0 libhiredis0.10 libhogweed2 libicu52 libnettle4 libregexp-common-perl
```